# pasted HTML not working

Tags: html, wordpress

I am pasting an HTML table into my wordpress site from Text Editor. The table is styled with CSS and both codes are correct.

Whether I paste it in to Wordpress or the W3Schools tester, not all of the styling takes place. It seems to choose different td's, tr's to style when it wants to.

If I delete td class="name" and then type it back out, it all works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well...pasting the code here certainly wouldn't hurt. Also, you might need to reset some browser defaults on your website as far as CSS goes.

Comment: Its not the code, 100% certain. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with extra spaces or dents, it just picks random areas where it needs to be re-typed no matter where it was pasted.

I am just wondering if there is a commonly known problem when it comes to pasting code.

Answer (score 0):

If deleting " and retyping it, then I would think that is where the issue is. I have come across this in the past, and I pretty much just retyped each one. If you try pasting the code to something like notepadd++ or Sublime Text, it may remove the character formatting of the ". Then copy and paste it from there to Wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I edited my question cause it reformatted it.

All I have to do is retype every class and it works. Even when i put it in TextWrangler and it all gets "cleaned up" , it still doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried checking the output using Chrome developer tools? It could be outputting something like &quote instead of the actual " symbol.  Just a thought that came to mind. Usually, the actual text within the quote marks is fine, but the quotes themselves could be getting changed to the html character entity.

Comment: Another thing you could try is to use the Paste from MS Word tool in the WordPress editor..

Comment: I pasted the code into wordpress, published it, deleted and retyped in all the classes, republished it (looked good), and now when I paste in the table with all of the classes, it works. I guess I just had to type them in once for some reason

Comment: Glad to hear it..   Wordpress is awesome, but it can be a bit fidgety sometimes.